# Jasmine toThrowError fail, message "Error: Actual is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm building a Jasmine spec and writing `toThrowError` test.

```
 it("Should give time travel error", () => {
        const errorMsg = Logger.getLogsBetweenDates( { 
              fromDate : new Date("2017-01-06"),
              toDate : new Date("2017-01-05")});

        expect(errorMsg).toThrowError("Time travel error: fromDate must be befor toDate");
});
```

And im getting "Error: Actual is not a function" with no extra details.

- What is that `Actual`?
- The `Logger.getLogsBetweenDates` function is acutely throw the error, and the test is always fail. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What is that Actual?

As its name suggest, the `Actual` is the variable that contain the actual result from the tested function. what's your tested function actually returned.

Then, Jasmine take that `Actual` value and compare it with your `expect` value.
It's easier to understand when you see the source code [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.3/src/core/matchers/toThrowError.js).

Its happen in the code becuse the `Logger.getLogsBetweenDates` is throw an error, and `errorMsg` get no result; so the `Actual` is `undefined`, and the   `expect` function compare an `undefined` to the error message.

> what am i doing wrong?

You need to call the tested function **inside** of the `expect` function, like so:

```
it("Should give time travel error", () => {    
     expect(() => {
             Logger.getLogsBetweenDates( { 
                  fromDate : new Date("2017-01-06"),
                  toDate : new Date("2017-01-05")})
            }).toThrowError("Time travel error: fromDate must be befor toDate");
});
```

As shown [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.throwError%3C/code%3E).

Comment: In addition, you can also save your function as a variable and reference it in your test, e.g. `const failingFunction = () => [call-to-function-with-parameters];` and then do `expect(failingFunction).toThrowError('Error message');`